# Where is the Gedit icon in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: icons, gedit

Short version:
Where is the icon file that Ubuntu uses for Gedit in menu's etc?

Explanation:
I use cairo-dock in ubuntu. I added a shortcut to the panel for Gedit. Right now cairo-dock has given it the default question mark icon. I'd like to point cairo-dock to the proper icon for gedit. I've browsed through /usr/share and /usr/local/share searching for folders like "icons", "images" etc, but it is a bewildering jungle of different locations and folder called "icons".

Any pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it:

/usr/share/icons/Yaru/48x48/apps

file is named gedit.png

All other applications also seem to have an icon there. Found out that the default dark theme for Ubuntu 20.04 is named Yaru. That made the search a lot easier.